# NoMethodError in Browse#index - undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a new controller called browse and this is what I have inside it

```
class BrowseController < ApplicationController
def index
    @hashtags = Hashtag.all
end    
end
```

I'm trying to display all of the hashtags in view using this (views\browse\index.html.erb)

```
<ul> 
<% @post.hashtags.each do |h| %>

<li><%= h.hashtags %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Here's the error that I'm getting

```
NoMethodError in Browse#index
undefined method `hashtags' for nil:NilClass
```

My routes.rb

```
get'/browse' => 'browse#index', :as => :index
```

How can I fix this error to display the list in browse.html.erb?
And if I wanted to display them in descending order of date, where do I need to put that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use code in index view as follows:

```
<ul> 
<% @hashtags.each do |h| %>

<li><%= h.{field_name} %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Where  {field_name} must be the name of field included in `Hashtagm` model.

Comment: any idea how I can make the list be in descending order by `created_at`?

Comment: @hashtags = Hashtag.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC')

Comment: @hashtags = Hashtag.all.order('created_at DESC')

Answer (score 0):

You did `@hashtags = Hashtag.all` in the controller, while you do `@post.hashtags.each` in your view.

Maybe you should do `@hashtags.each` in your view too.

Comment: that makes sense. Any idea on the second part of the question? I'm hoping to display the full list in descending order by dates

Comment: this is off-topic, but which do you think is a better regex to parse hashtags? `/(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!\d+(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/i` or `/\B#(\w+)/i`